# How sizeof operator works in c

Tags: c

I wanted to know how sizeof operator works in C.In belown code i am expecting to get output 1 but getting 4 .Since p is pointing to first location and at first location there is character and its size should be one.

```
main()
{

char a[9]="amit";
int *p=&a;
 printf("%d",sizeof((char *)(*p)));
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you're asking for the size of a character *pointer* which is 4 in your implementation.

That's because you're casting the dereferenced `int` pointer `p` to a `char` pointer then asking for the size of that.

Breaking it down:

```
sizeof((char *)(*p))
       |       \__/
       |         \_ Dereference p to get an int.
       \___________/
             \_____ Convert that to a char * (size = 4).
```

If you want to treat the first character of your `int` (which is, after all, a character array you've cast anyway), you should use:

```
sizeof(*((char*)(p)))
```

That is the `int` pointer, cast back to a `char` pointer, and *then* dereferenced.

Breaking *that* down:

```
sizeof(*((char *)(p)))
       | \________/
       |         \_ Get a char * from p (an int *)
       \___________/
             \_____ Dereference that to get a char (size = 1).
```

Comment: am confused here if simply write sizeof(*p) should not i get one because *p gives value at location which in our case is a

Comment: @AMIT: no, because you're doing it in the wrong order. If you dereference and then cast that value to a `char*`, you end up with a `char*` (size 4). If you cast it to a `char*` and _then_ dereference, you end up with a `char` (size 1).

Answer (score 5):

You are  getting the size of the result of the cast `(char *)`, which  is a char * with size of 4. Of course you could just have said:

```
 printf( "%d", sizeof(a[0]) );
```

and one rather wonders why you didn't?

Answer (score 1):

For the above question answer is 4.
Here you are type casting an integer pointer to a char pointer.
That means now the integer pointer is holding chars.
For the sizeof operator default argument is int.
When you are passing like `sizeof((char *)(*p))` then it treats as `sizeof('a')`. This char a is promoted to an int. That's why you are getting 4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on a 32 bit system the piece of code should show the size of *p to be 4.On a 16 bit it would show 2(not being highly used in application world these days, but can be a used in embedded world based on the requirement of a system).
You have done a cast to a char*, this will affect the data representation but not the memory occupied by the pointer pointing to your data.