# am i doing this right? - C code

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, allocation

when i run this it says the size is 4 when it is really six.  it does this here:

```
printf("String Size: %u\n", sizeof some_string.basic_string);
```

i am new to c memory allocation and never used malloc before.  am i using malloc right?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct String String;

struct String {
  char *basic_string;
};

String String_New(char basic_string[]) {
  String temp;
  temp.basic_string = (char *) malloc(sizeof basic_string);
  strcpy(temp.basic_string, basic_string);
  return temp;
}

void String_Delete(String *string) {
  free(string->basic_string);
  string->basic_string = NULL;
}

int String_GetSize(String string) {
  int i = 0, s = 0;
  while (string.basic_string[i] != '\0') {
    i++;
    s++;
  }
return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  String some_string = String_New("hello");
  printf("String Literal: %s\n", some_string.basic_string);
  printf("String Size: %u\n", sizeof some_string.basic_string);
  printf("String Length: %d\n", String_GetSize(some_string));
  String_Delete(&some_string);

  if (some_string.basic_string == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Either `s` or `i` in your `String_GetSize` is redundant.  I would remove `s`, as `i` is the more common (idiomatic) usage for an index or loop counter.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use object-oriented patterns in C.  Is there a reason you're not using C++ (or C# or Java)?

Comment: i dont like java or c# and idk why im not doing this is c++

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. Do you mean "in C++"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How sizeof operator works in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343514/how-sizeof-operator-works-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C a "string" is not a true data type.  The sizeof operator takes a data type, or an object that has "type" as an operand.  In your case the object is `some_string.basic_string` which has type `char*`, and the size of a pointer on your system is 4.

The solution is to define your String structure to have a size member:

```
struct String {
  char *basic_string;
  size_t length ;
};
```

And store the size when allocated in `String_New()`.  This would simplify and make more efficient your `String_GetSize()` function (which is already over complicated since s == i).

Be aware also that in `String_New()`, that the `basic_string` parameter is also a pointer (despite the "array syntax" used in its signature).  I would avoid this syntax, it is misleading since in C you cannot pass an array by copy unless the array is embedded in a struct; arrays always "degrade" to pointers when passed as arguments.  Moreover the caller may pass a pointer rather than an array in any case.  So in most cases you will have allocated too little memory (4 bytes). You should use `strlen()` or the method you originally used in `String_GetSize()` to determine the length.

```
String String_New(char* basic_string) 
{
  String temp;
  temp.length = strlen( basic_string ) ;
  temp.basic_string = (char *) malloc( temp.length + 1 );

  strcpy(temp.basic_string, basic_string);
  return temp;
}

size_t String_GetSize(String string) 
{
    return string.length ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`char *basic_string;` is a pointer to some memory, the size of the pointer (on a 32bit system) is 32bits = 4bytes.  Sizeof doesn't know about the size of memory you have reserved at this address.

There is generally no way to get the size of memory reserved by malloc - although your system may have some private debugging features to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In your helper function String_New(), you are asking for the size of the pointer as opposed to the size of the string when you say "sizeof(basic_string)", thats why you get 4 and not 6.  I think what you want is this:-

```
String String_New(const char* basic_string) {
  String temp;
  temp.basic_string = (char *) malloc(strlen(basic_string)+1);
  strcpy(temp.basic_string, basic_string);
  return temp;
}
```

sizeof measures the sizes of types at compile time; your string arguments will be runtime variables.

Comment: not `strlen(basic_string)`, but `strlen(basic_strng)+1` so I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `malloc` inside your `String_New` should use the **actual run-time length of the string**, e.g.

```
String String_New(char basic_string[]) {
  String temp;
  int length = strlen(basic_string);
  temp.basic_string =
     (char *) malloc(length+1); /* 1 more byte for terminating \0 */
  strcpy(temp.basic_string, basic_string);
  return temp;
}
```

but you should just use `strdup` e.g. `temp.basic_string = strdup (basic_string);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're expecting `sizeof` to do the same thing that `strlen()` does, or what your `String_GetSize()` does.  That's not what it's intended for.

You're performing `sizeof` on the `char*` pointer, i.e. "what is the size of this `char*`", which is a different question from "how long is the string pointed to by this `char*`".  On most (if not all) 32-bit platforms `sizeof(char*)` will in fact be `4`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong in your func `String_New`,when you pass `basic_string` to `String_New`, it is a pointer actually, that is `char *`.So, in 32bit machine, `sizeof(char *)` is 4